# querySelector criteria based on class and ID at the same time

Tags: javascript, dom, queryselector

In this HTMl code :

```
      <div class="modal__actions">
        <button class="btn btn--passive">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn--success">Add</button>
      </div>
    
    <div class="modal" id="delete-modal">
      <h2 class="modal__title">Are you sure?</h2>
      <p class="modal__content">
        Are you sure you want to delete this item? This action can't be made
        undone!
      </p>
      <div class="modal__actions">
        <button class="btn btn--passive">No (Cancel)</button>
        <button class="btn btn--danger">Yes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to reach to :
`<button class="btn btn--passive">No (Cancel)</button>`
item , I know there are different ways, but I am trying to use querySelector, I tried these commands but none of them selected what I was looking for:

```
const r1=document.querySelector('#delete-modal .btn btn--passive')
const r2=document.querySelector('#delete-modal, .btn btn--passive')
const r3=document.querySelector('.btn btn--passive, #delete-modal ')
```

Isn't it possible to use  class and ID at the same time on querySelector ?

Answer (score 1):

You should not have any space between the classes `btn` and `btn--passive` as they are for the same element. Also, you should prefix the class symbol for all the classes:

```js
const r1=document.querySelector('#delete-modal .btn.btn--passive');
console.log(r1);
```

```html
<div class="modal__actions">
    <button class="btn btn--passive">Cancel</button>
    <button class="btn btn--success">Add</button>
  </div>

<div class="modal" id="delete-modal">
  <h2 class="modal__title">Are you sure?</h2>
  <p class="modal__content">
    Are you sure you want to delete this item? This action can't be made
    undone!
  </p>
  <div class="modal__actions">
    <button class="btn btn--passive">No (Cancel)</button>
    <button class="btn btn--danger">Yes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```